# Google Analytics is overcounting users from Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I've been developing a new Android App for the past few days. I followed the Google Analytics v4 guide  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

I've only got the Android app connected to that Google Analytics account, nothing else whatsover.

I've only been using my android device in development, nothing else.

It's showing me 5 users so far, when it should be 1 user only. Even if it's a 1000 sessions, I don't care.

How does Google Analytics count users ?

I've made sure I'm only using the global tracker, nothing else, and I'm only initiating it once in the Application class of the android app. So I'm not loading the tracker many times.

Why is it overcounting ? I've always had this problem with Google Analytics even in previous SDK versions.

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Analytics counts the number of active used based on the number of unique [cid parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid). If you are re-installing the application or re-image the device the app will get new cid when it first starts. That will make it appear as new application instance to Google Analytics and result in higher users number.